# Brightway2 : what is the model pattern for an xlsx database?

Tags: python, excel, methods, brightway

I wanted to know if there is any .xlsx model to create my own Excel database that I'll import afterwards with Brightway2.
I use Ecoinvent and I want to make a LCI database from an excel import.
I vaguely know that the pattern is :
**Activity** "name of the activity I create" ;
unit ; Location ; production amount ; reference product ; database

Then
**Exchanges** "name" ; amount ; Location ; Unit ; database

But what if I wanna create an activity based on ecoinvent exchanges ? I can't put a reference product and a database ?
[Pic of my excel database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eJTK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brightway stores supply chains as graphs, with nodes and edges. We often call nodes "activities", but these can also be products, or elementary/biosphere flows, or however else you want to build your model. We also call edges exchanges. An edge links two nodes with a numerical amount. So, the only requirements are:

- Each node must have a `database` and a `code`, which together uniquely identify a node.
- Each edge must refer to the `database` and `code` of the source and target (aka input and output), and give an amount. Edges must also have a `type`, for the matrix builder to know which matrix the edges goes in (technosphere or biosphere), and the sign of the number (in the technosphere matrix, consumed inputs are negative, production is positive)

Everything else is optional, but for most humans, things like names, unit, locations, and reference products are convenient. I recommend you use them, but you can delete them from the template if you want.

You asked "But what if I wanna create an activity based on ecoinvent exchanges ? I can't put a reference product and a database?" I am not sure what would prevent you from getting the reference product, name, datbase label, or whatever of ecoinvent activities, this is quite normal.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Let me rephrase : I'm doing a modular IoT LCA, that's to say, I have an object composed of functional blocks like "Casing" that consists of multiple different components. In this manner, I decided to call (create because it doesn't exist in Ecoinvent) my activity "Casing", and the corresponding exchanges are my components like "market for aluminium". According to your claim, Activity needs a database but Casing doesn't exist in ecoinvent. How can I solve that ? Or, What should I do differently ?

Comment: A Brightway `Database` is just an organizational technique to put certain activities which have a logical connection together. So, we would normally store ecoinvent as a single `Database`, but you could also imagine an "ecoinvent (mobility)", "ecoinvent (all else)". Or, in your case, each casing could be its own `Database`, or you could lump all casings into a "casings" database, a "power supplies" database, a "microcontrollers" database, etc. There is no right way to draw these boundaries, it depends on the preference of the practitioner and project.

Answer (score 0):

BW allows you to customize your model ad hoc and there are some examples in the official docs, like [this one](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2/blob/master/notebooks/IO%20-%20importing%20an%20Excel%20file.ipynb). I have used a table format in .csv with these minimum headings (pattern): *Activity database;Activity code;Activity name;Activity unit;Activity type;Exchange database;Exchange input;Exchange amount;Exchange unit;Exchange type;Exchange uncertainty type;Exchange loc;Exchange scale;Exchange negative* See example [in this git repo](https://github.com/massimopizzol/advanced-lca-notebooks/blob/main/4-Excel-import.ipynb) to import [this dataset](https://github.com/massimopizzol/advanced-lca-notebooks/blob/main/test_db_excel_w_ecoinvent.csv) using this [ad hoc importer](https://github.com/massimopizzol/advanced-lca-notebooks/blob/main/lci_to_bw2.py)

Comment: My real question is about the correctness of my excel format database. Moreover, in activity, it seems necessary to put an reference product and a database but if I invented it (the activity), what'd I do ?

Comment: Seems like you are creating a new foreground system, which in Brightway means you need to create a new database, that you will link to ecoinvent (another database). What you miss is 1) give a name to your foreground activity. 2) Give a code to your foreground activity 3) give a name to your foreground database. For example: "Casing-Module", "010304892103", "ModularObjects" respectively